# How to run euclidean distance over and over in R

Tags: r

If I have a file in R like so

```
dput(filename)
structure(list(word = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("frq", 
"ocr_avg"), class = "factor"), abeja = c(98, 24), abeja.1 = c(26.666, 
3), abrigo = c(53.333, 6), abrigo.1 = c(50, 1), abrigo.2 = c(83.809, 
21), abrigo.3 = c(31.666, 6)), .Names = c("word", "abeja", "abeja.1", 
"abrigo", "abrigo.1", "abrigo.2", "abrigo.3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")

#      word abeja abeja.1 abrigo abrigo.1 abrigo.2 abrigo.3
# 1 ocr_avg    98  26.666 53.333       50   83.809   31.666
# 2     frq    24   3.000  6.000        1   21.000    6.000
```

And I want to calculate the euclidean distance between pairs with the same name, so for example between (abeja & abeja.1), then between (abrigo & abrigo.1) and (abrigo & abrigo.2) and (abrigo & abrigo.3). but also between (abrigo.1 & abrigo.2) and (abrigo.2 & abrigo.3).

Is there a way to automate this so that I don't have to go through every pair and do it myself (it's a pretty big file) in R?

The way I'm doing this on my own is like this:

```
x <- filename$abeja
y <- filename$abeja.1 
dist(rbind(x,y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mystring <- names(filename)

library(stringr)

# take the common patterns
strUniq <- unique(ifelse(str_detect(mystring, '\\.'), 
                         str_sub(mystring, 1, str_locate(mystring, '\\.')[,1] -1), 
                         mystring))
strUniq

# [1] "word"   "abeja"  "abrigo"

library(dplyr)
outp <- lapply(strUniq, function(x) select(filename, starts_with(x)))
outp

# [[1]]
#      word
# 1 ocr_avg
# 2     frq
#
# [[2]]
#   abeja abeja.1
# 1    98  26.666
# 2    24   3.000
#
# [[3]]
#   abrigo abrigo.1 abrigo.2 abrigo.3
# 1 53.333       50   83.809   31.666
# 2  6.000        1   21.000    6.000

lapply(outp, function(x) dist(t(x)))

# [[1]]
# dist(0)
#
# [[2]]
#            abeja
# abeja.1 74.36087
#
# [[3]]
#             abrigo  abrigo.1  abrigo.2
# abrigo.1  6.009067                    
# abrigo.2 33.967434 39.281656          
# abrigo.3 21.667000 19.003567 54.257649
#
# Warning message:
# In dist(t(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

The warning is due to "word" which does not contain numbers. You can remove it first to avoid the warning.

Comment: Hi, so I had more time today to look through the output and for words that have another word within it, it will pair those  together. so for example "ente" and "fuente". Is there anything that can be added so it doesn't do this?

Comment: try usisng `starts_with` in place of `contains`.
I will also edit my answer doing that.